# How to create EditorPart like windowbuilder in eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, windowbuilder

I have already had a `TextEditor` for my language extending with syntax highlighting, hyperlink detector and etc plugins. Also I have had an `EditorPart` for visual programming in the same language. How can I merge both editors in one Part with two switchable tabs like in WindowBuilder (tabs "Source" and "Design")?

Comment: Unfortunately your question boils down to "somebody please please help me with this". But we do not regard such requests as *questions* in the scope of this site. Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) carefully to understand why that is. Then consider to either delete this question and putting up a new, more precise question within the scope of this community. Alternatively, you could rework and improve this question. Thanks!

Comment: That ... or "too broad". I think you need to ask a more specific question in order to receive helpful feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use an editor part extending `MultiPageEditorPart` to create an editor with multiple pages.

This editor has a `createPages` method where you add the pages to the editor by calling the `addPage` method.

The New Plug-in Project wizard can actually create a skeleton of such an editor as one of its examples - make sure you select 'This plug-in will make contributions to the UI' on the second page of the wizard. The final page will then include 'Multi-page editor' in the list of examples.

Comment: Can you help me a little more?
How to get text from dirty texteditor?

Comment: If you want more help ask a new question about a specific problem.